# Как установить lcurses на Lua 5.3?

Tags: lua, ncurses, curses

На оф.сайте указано, что `curses` содержится в пакете `luaposix`, который уже установлен, однако при попытке подкючить пакет `curses` интерпретатор выдаёт ошибку из-за того, что пакет не установлен/существует

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, вам нужно делать `require"posix"`, а не "подключить пакет `curses`".

Почитайте, пожалуйста, документацию по LuaPosix (там даже примеры есть, и, вроде, даже, были оные с curses)